# File Reader Method

Tags: java, logic, bufferedreader, filereader

So I wrote this file reader method that should return a string of everything that is in the file, but it isn't working properly. Writing into the file works perfectly, but this reading method doesn't. What the method does currently is it reads the last string/text added, but it does not read the file from start to finish. 'br' is my bufferedReader, which is declared somewhere else in the same class. 
Here's how br is defined:

```
private static FileInputStream fis;
private static BufferedReader br;
```

and then in the constructor:

```
fis = new FileInputStream(file);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Here's the method:

```
public String readStuff(){
    String line = "";
    String r = "";
    try{
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line + " read ");
            r+= line;
        }
        //br.close(); JDK 7 does this automatically apparently
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error at readStuff!");
    }
    return r;
```

I know I'm making either a logic mistake or some obvious error, I just don't know where.

Comment: `I know I'm making either a logic mistake or some obvious error, I just don't know where. ` What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: How are you defining br?

Comment: So you're using the same `BufferedReader` instance more than once? Do you ever seek it back to the beginning of the file?

Comment: oh yeah I should probably add that i'll edit it

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I'm not sure exactly how to do that, could you explain (that might be my solution) ?

Comment: This code will read everything in the file, once. NB Java 7 doesn't automatically close anything using this syntax. You should close it manually. You will then probably discover that you're calling this method more than once ;-)

Comment: @EJP where do you think I should close it? I took close() out because it was causing me problems...

Comment: Exactly. It was telling you that you were calling the method after you had already closed the file. The first time, it read the entire file. The second time, after you removed the `close(),` the file was still open, so it gave you whatever had been added to the file since the first time. If you want to read the entire file twice, you will have to close it and open new streams. But there is something wrong with the application if it needs to keep re-reading the same file. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: It re-reads it because every time the user types into a JTextField and hits enter, text is added to the file and a Jlabel is updated with all the text from that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the entire file twice, you will have to close it and open new streams/readers next time.

Those streams/readers should be local to the method, not members, and certainly not static.

Answer (score 0):

Using File and `FileReader` You can Read / Write File From Dir.

you can get File using `File` class object

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

and After Process to read that file

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
```

There are Whole Code to read File...

```
File file = new File("G:\\Neon\\data.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        String data = "";
        while((i = fr.read()) != -1)
        {
            data = data + (char)i;
        }
System.out.println(data);
```